# Save a .json chrome addon

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I've seen people asking how to load a .json config file to a chrome addon.

But I dont understand how that can be useful if you can't write to it?

Is there any way to write to a JSON file that is inside your app-directory?

(I know localStorage exists)

Here's how I would get the .json file

```
$.getJSON(chrome.extension.getURL('/config_resources/config.json'), function(settings) {
  //..
});
```